Isomorphisms in $A\downarrow G$ are iso's in $\operatorname{dom}G$?
Let $G\colon D\to C$ be a functor and $A$ an object of $C$. Let $g\colon (B_1, f_1)\to (B_2, f_2)$ be an iso in $A\downarrow G$. Does this mean that $g\colon B_1\to B_1$ is an iso in $D$?
The answer is a resounding negative. (Take $C$ to be the discrete singleton cat.)
But, this is exactly what seems to be used by Peter Smith in Theorem 245 of his Introducing Category Theory:

Theorem 245. If a functor has an adjoint, it is unique up to natural isomorphism. If $F\dashv G$ and $F\dashv G'$, then $G\cong G'$. If $F\dashv G$ and $F'\dashv G$ then $F\cong F'$.
Proof. Suppose we have both $F\dashv G\colon C\to D$ with unit $\eta$ and $F' ⊣ G: C → D$ with unit $η′$.
By Theorem 251, for any $C$-object $A$, both $(F A, η_A)$ and $(F'A, η'_A )$ are initial objects of $(A ↓ G)$. So, as initial objects, there must be an isomorphism $α_A$ between them, which by the definition of arrows in $(A ↓ G)$ means we have an isomorphism $α_A : FA → F'A$ in $D$ such that $η'_A = Gα_A \circ η_A$. Likewise, of course, we have an isomorphism $α_{A'} :FA' →F'A'$ such that $η'_{A'} =Gα_{A'}\circ η_{A'}$.
It is then easy to show that $α_A , α_{A'}, \ldots$ assemble into a natural isomorphism $α:F⇒F'$, and therefore – as claimed – $F\cong F'$.

Can someone explain me what's going on here?

Please do not use images.

Yes, there is a projection functor $U : A \downarrow G \to D$ that takes $g$ to $U(g) : B_1 \to B_2$, and since all functors preserve isomorphisms $U(g)$ is an isomorphism in $D$ if $g$ is an isomorphism in $A \downarrow G$.

@ArturoMagidin, done.

@NaïmFavier Please avoid answering questions in the comment section. This is not how comments are supposed to be used. See here for more information.

Your supposed counterexample is mistaken. If $G : D \to 1$ is the unique functor to the terminal category, an object of $A \downarrow G$ is an object $d$ of $D$ together with a morphism $Gd \to A$. Since both $Gd$ and $A$ have to be the unique object of $1$, this map must be the identity of that object, so it doesn't contribute anything. So effectively an object of $A \downarrow G$ is just an object of $D$. I'll still denote the objects as $(d, \_)$, where $\_$ just stands for the required morphism.
Next, a morphism $(d, \_) \to (d', \_)$ in $A \downarrow G$ is a morphism $f : d \to d'$ such that $id_* \circ Gf = id_*$. Again, these morphisms are all the identity in $1$, so this triangle trivially commutes. This means that really the only information here is the morphism $f : d \to d'$.
For $f : (d, \_) \to (d', \_)$ to be an isomorphism, we require an inverse: a morphism $g : (d', \_) \to (d, \_)$ such that $f \circ g$ and $g \circ f$ are the identity. Since composition in $A \downarrow G$ is composition in $D$ (plus the fact that the commuting triangles add together to make a big commuting triangle), this just means that the compositions of the morphisms from $d$ to $d'$ and $d'$ to $d$ are the identity. This implies that they are themselves isomorphisms.

More generally, any functor at all preserves isomorphisms and $A \downarrow G$ has a forgetful functor to $D$ that maps the pair $(d, f)$ to $d$ and for morphisms just forgets the commuting triangle. So if we have an isomorphism in $A \downarrow G$, it drops to an isomorphism in $D$.
